# Sort v-for over an object (Vue2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using `Vue2` and try to sort a `v-for`. I am iterating over an object and the vue-doc states:

> When iterating over an object, the order is based on the key
>   enumeration order of Object.keys(), which is not guaranteed to be
>   consistent across JavaScript engine implementations.

My `v-for` without sorting looks like this:

```html
<my-component :key="key + value + uid" 
v-for="(value,key) in myObject" :key-prop="key" 
:value-prop="value"></my-component>
```

How would I sort this if the Object.keys() are not consistent?

Edit: This is an example Object (returned from Rest-Service)

Chrome console logs this:

```
{
HUMID: "66%"
DAY: "true"
TEMP: "30"
}
```

The actual object is much larger.

Edit2:

With the help of "Oli Crt" I solved this. I wasn't able to calculate the sortedObjects as a computed property in my case, but I triggered it on getting the Response of my Rest-Service.

```js
sortObject: function() {
    this.myObjectSorted =  Object.keys(this.myObject).sort();
}
```

This results in the following Object:

```
{
0: "DAY"
1: "HUMID"
2: "TEMP"
}
```

By taking the value of this sorted Object as my key-prop and getting the actual value (66%, true, 30) of the unsorted Object with

```js
myObject[value]
```

I got the desired result.

```html
<my-component :key="key + value + uid" 
v-for="(value,key) in myObjectSorted" :key-prop="value" 
:value-prop="myObject[value]"></my-component>
```

Comment: Do you want to sort the order of the list based on some user actions?

Comment: It would be enough to sort by the parameter name (the key-prop). It does not need to sort again after the initial sorting.

Comment: Could you add a sample object to the question?

Comment: It matters how you would sort the object based on its property you wish.

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069840/5640621 Convert the object to array and use in `v-for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a computed property.
You could sort the keys of your object

```
 computed: {
   myObjectSorted: function () {
     return Object.keys(this.myObject).sort(...); // Do your custom sorting here
   }
 }
```

Then use myObject[key] with the key from myObjectSorted in v-for.